# How can I exclude certain text in mobile version of site?

Tags: iphone

I want to exclude some HTML (basically,  text ) when my PHP site loads on a smartphone. What's the best way to code that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if "on a smartphone" means "on a small device", you could use Media Query , just with CSS.

```
<style>
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
      .hide-mobile{ 
        display:none;
      }
    }
</style>
```

And use it where you want to hide at small devices:

```
<div class="hide-mobile">
    Hey, this text is not visible at small devices
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go really simple, just use mediaqueries in your CSS to make the div be display:none; for mobile.

```
@media only screen 
and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .containeroftextyouwanttohide{ 
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Then the div holding the text you want won't show up on mobile. There are probably other ways to do it, but this is the easiest and probably best.

Comment: Wow. I didn't realize it was that easy! Thanks!